# Evaluate $\left(\frac{3}{11}\right)$ using Euler's Criterion...

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, euler-lagrange-equation

Evaluate $\left(\frac{3}{11}\right)$ using Euler's Criterion.

So far I have:

$$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) =a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\implies \left(\frac{3}{11}\right)=3^{\frac{11-1}{2}}=3^5$$

I am a bit lost from here, any help is appreciated, from my understanding the answer should be $\pm 1$ but I do not understand how to arrive at that.

Comment: Just compute it by hand, it's not that bad.  $3^2=-2\implies 3^4=4\implies 3^5=?$

Comment: But then you get 243, which is 1 (mod 11). Is this correct? Looking back at my work I miscalculated.

Comment: Absolutely.  It's easier, though to try to avoid large numbers.  In this case, as $3^4=4$ we get $3^5=12=1$.  This is the big advantage of modular arithmetic.  In this particular case, I agree that you can just multiply it out.

Comment: Just to check the answer, let's find the square root.  Again we'll proceed by brute force and note that $\{\pm1,\pm 2,\pm3,\pm 4,\pm 5\}$ square to $\{1,4,2,5,3\}$ so we see that the square root of $3 \pmod {11}$ is $\pm 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Euler's criterion is used in a prime modulus $p$.

So, if $a\in U_p$, and $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1$ mod $p$, then $\exists x\in U_p$ such that $x^2=a$ (a quadratic residue). If it is -1, then there is no such $x\in U_p$.